# Proof of convergence of integral representation of the Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The Gamma Function defined by :    $\Gamma(n) = \displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1} dx$    This can be written as:   $\displaystyle\Gamma(n) = \int_0^1 e^{-x} x^{n-1} dx + \int_1^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1} dx$    Now the convergence of the $1$st first integral is clear to me but I am not sure about the $2$nd integral. Our professor did the proof in the following way :  $\displaystyle e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\ldots  > \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\$ $\implies e^{-x} x^{n-1} < \frac{{(n+1)!}{x^{n-1}}}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{(n+1)!}{x^2}\\$ Integrating both sides from 1 to infinity :$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1}dx < \small(n+1)! \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}\\$ Now since $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ is convergent ( I have that proof ) So by Comparison test $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1}dx$ is also convergent. I think the proof is wrong because firstly while expanding the series of $e^x$ how can she write $\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ , this term using $n$ because till then I have no idea about the value of $n$ and writing this term means that $n \geq 0$ and here on the contrary we need to find the restriction over $n$ for which this integral converges. If this step is correct then the rest of the proof is pretty simple to unterstand. Can anyone tell me whether the proof is correct or if it is wrong, in which part it is and how to do it correctly ?

$Edits: \\ \\$
Most of the comments and answers mentioned that my professor must have assumed $n$ to be $>0$. But that's not the case. Instead she intends to find the interval of $n$ for which $\Gamma$ - Function converges. From the first part i.e. the integral from 0 to 1 she derived the condition $n > 0$. But that has no connection with the $2$nd part i.e. the integral from $1$ to $\infty$. *She didn't assume any restriction on $n$* . That's why I asked this question here. I request everyone to please add the proof of the 2nd part without assuming any restriction on $n\\$.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like your professor is looking at gamma only for $n$ to be a non-negative integer. Is that right? (Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the expansion of $e^x$ in that way)

Comment: @NazimJ The expansion of $e^x$ is fine.  For $\text{Re}(z)>0$, we have  $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt$.  Then, take $n\ge \text{Re}(z)+1$, and we can still proceed as in the OP.

Comment: @NazimJ No no she didn't assume anything about $n$ instead she is finding the interval of $n$ for which Gamma Function converges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\text{Re}(z)>0$, we can represent the Gamma Function by the integral

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{z-1}\,dx$$

---

For any integer $n$ and $x\ge0$, we have the bound

$$e^x\ge \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

---

Now, we fix the number $z$ and we ***choose*** an integer $n\ge \max(1,\text{Re}(z)+1)$.  Then, we can assert

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_1^\infty e^{-x}x^{z-1}\,dx\right|&\le \int_1^\infty e^{-x}x^{\text{Re}(z)-1}{x}\,dx\\\\
&\le \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{\text{Re}(z)-1}}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}\,dx\\\\
&=(n+1)!\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+(n-\text{Re}(z))}}\,dx\\\\
&\le (n+1)!\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}\,dx
\end{align}$$

And the integral converges for this fixed $z$.

---

Of course, this fixed value of $z$ was arbitrary.  So, for any other $z$, we can choose an integer $n\ge \max(1,\text{Re}(z)+1)$ and arrive at the same conclusion that $\int_1^\infty e^{-x}x^{z-1}\,dx$ converges.

Comment: Actually my professor did not assume anything about $z$, instead she derived the interval of $z$ for which Gamma Function converges. She derived the condition that $n>0$ for the convergence of the integral from 0 to 1 . But for the 2nd part without assuming anything about $z$ she just proved that the integral ***always*** converges.

Comment: I didn't assume anything about $z$ aside from bounding its real part below by $0$.  I could have ommitted that assumption of course and then show that the integral converges only when $\text{Re}(z)>0$.  But note that we learn that we must have $\text{Re}(z)>0$ from analyzing the integral over $[0,1]$.  And I thought your question only concerned the integral over $[1,\infty$.  Does this make sense now?

Comment: I've edited the last paragraph to address your comment.  In the analysis, we don't assume anything about $z$ for the integration on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: So that means for the integration on $[1,\infty]$ , $z$ can be any number(real or complex) and $Re(z) > 0$ is only for the integration over [0,1] and combining both we get the common condition $Re(z) > 0$ ?

Comment: Also one more thing, in the 2nd para, $n$ must be a positive integer isn't it ?

Comment: @esha You have it.  Well done.  And yes,  for the bound of the exponential function, $n$ is an integer as the bound comes from Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: If $n$ is negative integer then how can we calculate the factorial of a negative number ??

Comment: @esha Of course if $\text{Re}(z)\le 0$, then we can choose $n=1$ and the estimate holds.  So, I've edited so that $n\ge \max(1,\text{Re}(z)+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic behavior of the integrand is

$$\sim x^{n-1}$$ near $0$, which integrates as $$\sim\frac{x^n}n,$$ ($\log x$ for $n=0$) and

$$\lesssim e^{-x}\max(x^{n-1},1)$$ near $\infty$, which integrates like $$\lesssim p_n(x)e^{-x}$$ for $n>0$ where $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $\max(n,0)$.

Hence, the integral in $(1,\infty)$ causes no problem, while that in $(0,1)$ only works for $n>0$.